# Google App Engine: Receiver not reacing to deployed GCM messages

Tags: android, google-app-engine, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, intentfilter

I am trying to use google cloud messaging server. I followed [this guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints) to do it. I was **managed and succeeded** to: add the backend to Android Studio, get API key, adding the GcmRegistrationAsyncTask, GcmIntentService and GcmBroadcastReceiver classes to my code as followed in the guide.

When I run the app on my physical device, this message appears in the log: "I/REGISTRATION﹕ Device registered", but nothing happens when I send a message from the app engine console on appengine.google.com. I am supposed to get the message as a toast.

I suspect that the problem might be related to declaring the intent. I tried to do it either in the AndroidManifest, and in the code:

**in AndroidManifest:**

```
<receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com\example\android\meand100_2" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in **MainActivity**, under onCreate method:

```
    new GcmRegistrationAsyncTask(this).execute();
    registerBroadcastReceiver();
```

the registerBroadcastReceiver method:

```
public void registerBroadcastReceiver() {

    this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Registered broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

I will appriciate any help! thanks.

Comment: It would be better follow the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). You may have missed something. Comparing the official documentation and the one that you followed you missed the part where you should get `google-services.json`. Check for other things that you may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide here:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

You're supposed to register a receiver in your manifest that is defined in the GCM client library. This is the receiver that actually receives the intent from GCM, and then starts a Service locally in your package. Then you should do the work in a custom Service.

The guide that I linked above should help, but you can also reference this sample project:
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main